# What is the best single measure of brain networks based on functional MRI data?

Tags: correlation, multiple-comparisons

I want to analyze functional MRI ([fMRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_magnetic_resonance_imaging)) data as follows:

1. I am comparing the brain networks of two groups of subjects (patients and matched).
2. For each subject I have a correlation (Pearson) matrix with the correlations between multiple brain regions (above 50000 correlations).
3. I want to get a single measure to represent every subject (maybe the mean of correlations of each subject network). **What is the most suitable measure?** Should I use Fisher transformation to average the correlation matrix?
4. I assume that the variance of the two groups is different and that the variance in each group is similar: **How can check that without doing multiple comparisons?**

Comment: Do you really want to do an FMRI analysis with absolutely no chance of localization of the functional differences?

Comment: I am comparing voxels correlations within specific regions of interest, so it is localized.

Comment: ah, so you just want to see which group's region X better correlates.

Comment: Several regions, but yes.

Comment: Whether it's physically the same region is irrelevant, only whether you're treating the same functionally... since that's what you're studying.

Comment: I agree. I'm treating the same Functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, z-transform to average the functional regions within S and then compare them as you'd normally compare correlations between groups... is your simplest path.  Otherwise, I thought FSL had a facility to handle such comparisons of the magnitude of an effect with multi-level modelling.

Comment: I'm using brain voyager. Anyway I wanted to know how to do it theoretically. Thank you.